# Using CSS's "revert" keyword

Tags: javascript, css, polyfills, css-cascade

So I've been trying to work on some classes that hide and show elements. When an element is supposed to show, it should go from `display:none;` to `display: whatever-it-was-before;`. In researching ways to do this, I stumbled across what looks to be the perfect solution: CSS's `revert`. Unfortunately, Cascading and Inheritance Level 4 is a long ways from being supported, and this feature doesn't appear to be implemented in any of the major browsers on Windows.

To illustrate what I'm trying to do, here's some CSS:

```css
.article-card {
    display: flex;
}
._showdesktop {
    display: none !important;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    ._showdesktop {
        display: revert !important;
    }
}
```

And some accompanying HTML:

```html
<div class="article-card _showdesktop">
    ...
</div>
```

The idea is to have generic classes that can be used on any element, without overriding the intended CSS of an element. This would allow me to show and hide elements that are `display:flex;`, `display:block;`, `display:inline-block;`, or `display:inline;` all with the same set of classes.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there any polyfill out there for this? I tried searching around, but unfortunately the terms "revert" and "polyfill" show up together a lot thanks to version control systems.
2. Is there any other way to do this with CSS? I was looking in to using `visibility:hidden;`, as I almost never use the `visibility` property in my projects, but this doesn't remove an element from the flow, and I couldn't think of any way to remove it that wouldn't conflict with other code.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#default

---

**Update:** The answer marked below is as good as I'm going to get for now, but I wanted to update this question with the code I ended up using. I'm not sure how well this will work, considering I do often use max-height, but hopefully it won't conflict very often:

```css
._hidemobile,
._showtablet,
._showdesktop {
    max-height: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

._showmobile {
    max-height: none !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    ._showmobile,
    ._hidetablet {
        max-height: 0 !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }

    ._showtablet {
        max-height: none !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    ._showtablet,
    ._hidedesktop {
        max-height: 0 !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }

    ._showdesktop {
        max-height: none !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as CSS4. Probably, you mean [CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/)

Comment: My jaw dropped in excitement there for a second

Comment: @Oriol sorry, I'm not sure I understand the difference. I thought "level 4" meant the working draft for CSS4. Could you clarify why thats incorrect?

Comment: @Rev See [A Word About CSS4](http://www.xanthir.com/b4Ko0). Basically, CSS was modularized, and now each module has its own version. In this case, Cascade has level 4. But the language itself is still CSS3.

Comment: @Oriol, ah, very interesting, thanks for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Is there any polyfill out there for this? I tried searching around, but unfortunately the terms "revert" and "polyfill" show up together a
>      lot thanks to version control systems.

Probably not. `revert` rolls back the cascade, that's a non-trivial thing.

Moreover, I'm not sure it would be helpful in your case. You style an element with `display: flex` but `display: none` wins the cascade. If I understand correctly, you want to undo `display: none` and get `display: flex`. However, [`revert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#valdef-all-revert)

> Rolls back the cascade to the user level, so that the [specified
>   value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#specified-value) is calculated as if no author-level rules were specified for
>   this property.

That is, your author-level `display: flex` will be ignored too.

Instead, `display: revert` is useful when you want to reset `display` to the default behavior, e.g. `block` for `<div>`, `table-cell` for `<td>`, `inline` for `<span>`.

> 2. Is there any other way to do this with CSS? I was looking in to using `visibility:hidden;`, as I almost never use the `visibility`
>      property in my projects, but this doesn't remove an element from the
>      flow, and I couldn't think of any way to remove it that wouldn't
>      conflict with other code.

Yes. As you suspect, `display: none` is an oddity which should have never existed. [CSS Display Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) addresses this issue by introducing a new property, called [`box-suppress`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-box-suppress):

> The [`display: none`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-display) value was historically used as a "toggle" to
>   switch between showing and hiding an element. Making this reversible
>   requires either setting up the CSS [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascade) carefully, or
>   remembering what the [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-display) value was before it was set to
>   [`none`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-none). To make this common use-case easier, this module
>   introduces the separate [`box-suppress`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-box-suppress) property to do the same
>   thing, so that toggling whether or not an element appears in the
>   formatting tree can now be done without affecting its display type
>   when it *is* displayed.

The "only" problem is that no major browser supports `box-suppress` neither.

So meanwhile, the best approach is applying `display: none` only when you need it, so that you won't have to undo it. In your example,

```css
.article-card {
  display: flex;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) { /* This rule is optional */
  ._showdesktop {
    /* Use current display */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  ._showdesktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="article-card _showdesktop">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: A ton of good information here, thanks much! Sounds like I'll just have to wait a few years for browser support to catch up :/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question and I don't think this answer is immediately applicable (any "revert" value appears to have been removed, and 'box-suppress' was never implemented either), but the current way to achieve this appears to be:

```
display: "contents";
```

Using this and a wrapper element it is now possible to "undo" a `display: "none";` because the `"contents"` type does not generate a block in the document flow (just like `"none"`) but it does place its contents into the flow.

Some examples:

```js
var toggle = 'contents'
btn = document.getElementById('showHide');
btn.onclick = function(ev) {
  toggle = ('none' === toggle) ? 'contents' : 'none'
  var disp = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle')
  disp.forEach( el => el.style.display = toggle )
}
```

```css
.toggle { border: 1px dotted red; }
```

```html
<section>
<p>
On first load, display is the browser default and outlines the elements under test. Each click toggles display:none/display:contents.<br>
<button id="showHide">TOGGLE DISPLAY</button>
</p>

<div>
Text above the first toggle element.
<span class="toggle">Text in the first toggle element.</span>
Text below the first toggle element. Note that everything flows together.
</div>

<p></p>

<div>
In a new div now, a list comes next.
<ol><li>AAA</li>
    <li class="toggle">BBB</li>
    <li>CCC</li>
</ol>
This text is after the list. The second &lt;li&gt; becomes its content.
<hr>

Here's a list that will toggle the display property on itself:
<ol class="toggle"><li>JJJ</li>
    <li>KKK</li>
    <li>LLL</li>
</ol>
When displayed again, the &lt;od&gt; is gone, but the &lt;li&gt; remain.
<hr>

This list has an embedded dev.
<ol><li>XXX</li>
    <div class="toggle"> <li>YYY</li> </div>
    <li>ZZZ</li>
</ol>
This is invalid HTML but after becoming display:contents it should appear normal.

</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think most of the posters here understand what "revert" does? It only works in non-IE browsers, for starters. So not very helpful. On un-inherited properties like "display" it would "revert" back to the browser's UA default style sheet value for the element, not the author's sheet, which in this case would be "block" for the div.

Why don't you simply do the reverse, and only define your various divs in your media query when they are displayed?

```
._hidedesktop {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .article-card {
      display: flex;
  }
}

<div class="_hidedesktop article-card">
    ...
</div>
```